# polymer paper-button syntaxerror function statement requires a name

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want the function to be fired when i click on the button but somehow it gives me an error "syntaxerror: function statement requires a name" in the console.
What am i missing?

```
<link href="assets/polymer/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="test-button" attributes="">
  <template>
    <style>
    paper-button[default] {
      color: #4285f4;
    }
    </style>
    <paper-button label="Accept" onclick="{{ saveButton }}" default></paper-button>


    <div id="label"><content></content></div>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('test-button', {
      saveButton: function() {
        alert('button clicked');
      }
    });   


  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

to shorten my question: i left out the code of my main file where i import the element and display it with `<test-button></test-button>`.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `onclick` to `on-click`. This is using Polymer's declarative event handlers. And remove {{}} from polymar 1.